# Check if a IPC message queue already exists without creating it

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue

How can I just check if a message queue exists or not without making it?

When using `msgget` with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` flag, if it exists, the call will fail with return value -1, but if it doesn't, it will then create a new message queue. Is there any way to just check?

Comment: If you pass zero as the flags (or at least not pass the `IPC_CREAT` flag) , then the call will fail with `errno` set to `ENOENT` if there is no message queue with the specified key. I recommend you [read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I read the manual, didn't notice the `ENOENT` flag.

Answer (score 0):

ipcs(1) provides information on the IPC facilities and ipcrm(1) can be used to remove the IPC objects from the system.

List shared memory segments:

ipcs -m

List message queues:

ipcs -q

Remove shared memory segment created with shmkey:

ipcrm -M key

Remove shared memory segment identified by shmid:

ipcrm -m id

Remove message queue created with msgkey:

ipcrm -Q key

Remove message queue identified by msgid:

ipcrm -q id