# IPC message queue - Detect disconnect

Tags: c, crash, queue, ipc, message

I've got a 'problem' that's seems impossible to solve by myself. 
I've got the following 3 programm :

```
[   ]<------ [   ] ------>[   ]
[ A ]        [ B ]        [ C ]
[   ] ------>[   ]<------ [   ]
```

According to this diagram, A and B, and B and C use message queue in order to communicate.

B create the message queue that contains message for A.
A create the message queue that contains message for B.
Same goes for B and C. B create for C, C for B.

I select on those different message queues.
For exemple, B, connect on message queue from C and from A.
It select on those 2 in order to get message.

But here comes the problem. I would like to detect from B if A crash.
And if so, disconnect message queue and reconnect later when A comes back.

I've got no idea how to do so ... select does not return if A crash (that will indicate that A crash and then 'disconnect / delete' his message queue.

**Other information according to comments** : 
I'm on GNU/Linux, and I'm using 'mq_...' function

Do you have any idea ? Put a timer on the select and then, check that the message queue still exist ? If so how ?
Other idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: How to detect a "disconnect" really depends on the operating system and the implementation and functions you use.

Comment: More generally though, you could add a kind of "I'm alive" message that is sent and replied to. If the message (or its reply) isn't received in a while, consider the other end dead. or gone

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on linux, and I'm using the 'mq_...' function. I've found another of your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889356/check-if-a-ipc-message-queue-already-exists-without-creating-it. I'm trying to use this method right now. If it does not work, I'll try the "I'm alive" message :D thanks you !

Comment: Well .. I was not ready for this solution but, I did try your idea / answer on the previous post in the link above and ... it did indeed work without changing a lot in my code ! Thanks I'm going to upvote your comment on the link above !